# Cons Cell data structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree, scheme

I'm a newbie at C, in the early stages of building a small Scheme interpreter. For this part of the project I'm trying to build a simple cons cell data structure. It should take a list like

`(a b c)`

and represent it internally like so:

```
[ ][ ] -> [ ][ ] -> [ ][/]
 |         |         |
 A         B         C
```

To test that it's working correctly, I have a print function to to echo out the input. Here is the code that isn't working:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lexer.h"
#include "parse.h"

char token[20]; 


struct conscell {
    char *data;
    struct conscell *first, *rest;
};

void S_Expression ()
{   
    /* function from lexer to receive input a split into tokens no greater than 20 */
    startTokens(20);

    /* gets the next token */
    strcpy(token, getToken());

    /* List is a typedef for the struct conscell */
    List tree = createList ();
    tree = nextNode (tree);
    printList(tree);

}


List createList ()
{
    List node = malloc(sizeof (List));

    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->data = NULL;
    node->first = NULL;
    node->rest = NULL;

    return node;
}

/* Recursive function to build cons cell structure */
List nextNode (List node)
{
    node = createList ();

    if (token[0] == '(')
    {         
       strcpy(token, getToken());
       node->first = nextNode(node->first);
       node->rest = nextNode(node->rest);         
     }

    else
    {
       if (token[0] == ')')
       {
          node = NULL;
       }

       else
       {
           List temp = createList();
           temp->data = token;
           temp->first = NULL;
           temp->rest = NULL;

           node->first = temp;

           strcpy(token, getToken());
           node->rest = nextNode(node->rest);            
       }
   }
   return node;
}

/* Prints output. So far, just trying to print symbols */
void printList(List node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
      if (node->data != NULL)
      {        
        printf("%s", node->data);

      }
    }
}
```

So far can't print out anything. I'm almost positive its a pointer issue. If anyone could point me (no pun intended) in the right direction, it'd be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That's not a cons cell; a cons cell has only two members, `car` and `cdr`. There's also a memory leak in `nextNode`. You're also copying pointers to a buffer that subsequently gets overwritten.

Comment: -1: Jave you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or adding printf statements to display the values of variables throughout your code?  Also, you haven't provided the definition of `List`.

Comment: @larsmans thanks for the feedback, makes more sense now.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth yeah I used printf statements throughout the code to show different values, but hadn't noticed the buffer was overwritten every time. I took them out when I posted the question. Forgot to mention, List is a typedef for conscell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming `List` is a typedef for a `struct conscell*`.  If it's not, it should be, otherwise your code won't compile without tons of warnings.

A scheme cons cell should be a simple singly linked list, not a doubly-linked list.  So your individual cells should be more like:

```
typedef conscell 
{
    unsigned char *data;   //<== use unsigned char for a memory buffer
    struct conscell* next; //<== only a "next" pointer needed
} conscell;
```

I see you're just trying to print symbols at the moment, so using `char` rather than `unsigned char` can work for that purpose, but when you go with more generic data-structures like lambdas, etc., you're going to have to switch to either `unsigned char*` or `void*` for the reference to the memory buffer holding those types of more complex data-structures.

The other issue that seems a bit confusing is that you're making each cell of your cons cells another cons cell, for instance, these lines of code,

```
if (token[0] == '(')
{         
   strcpy(token, getToken());
   node->first = nextNode(node->first);
   node->rest = nextNode(node->rest);         
 }
```

are recursively adding cons cells as your "first" and "rest" ... but that's not how a linked-list should look like.  It should have a pointer to a list-node as the "head" of the list (not another cons-cell like it seems you're doing here), and then each node in the list points to some data and the next node in the list.

Next, you have memory leaks all over the place with your `createList()` function as you allocate memory with it, but then never delete that memory (i.e., you have code like `node = NULL` which effectively is a memory leak because you've lost the memory reference to the allocated memory location that `node` was originally pointing to).  You have to call `free()` on a node pointer before you assign `NULL` to it.

Finally, `printList()` doesn't do anything but print the first element of the list you pass it ... there are no recursive calls or loops to cycle to the next node in the linked list.  So you're not going to be printing much with that function.  It should look more like:

```
void printList(List node)
{
    List current = node;

    while (current != NULL)  //<== guard for the end-of-list
    {
      if (node->data != NULL)
      {        
        printf("%s", node->data);
      }

      current = current->next; //cycle to the next node in the linked list
    }
}
```

So to sum things up, 1) your cons data-structure should represent a singly linked list composed of a structure data-type having a data element and a pointer to the next node.  The cons'ed list is accessed through a head pointer pointing to the first node.  2) As you parse the input, you should add nodes to the front of the linked list since Scheme's `cons` operation, and really all the operations in scheme, are recursive, and "fold to the right", meaning they work from a base-case (i.e., the cons'ing of two elements), and then expand on that base-case.  So if you had something like `(cons 'd (cons 'c (cons 'b (cons 'a '()))))`, you'd the print the list `(d c b a)`.  If you want, it could also help to put tokens into a stack as your recursively parse the input, and then from the stack input into your linked list (sort of like how a RPN calculator would work).

Comment: Wow, thanks alot for the in-depth response. I should've mentioned that I was shooting for a recursive descent parser, does that change anything? Is it any different from using a singly-linked list? I like the stack idea, thanks. Will work on it using your advice tonight.

Comment: A recursive parser and a singly linked list are two seperate things.  You're storing your cons'd data after parsing in a singly linked list.  You should keep the two ideas separate so that no matter how you decide to parse the input data, it will be stored in a format that abstracts nicely to the application of that data.

Answer (score 0):

Also add \n to your printf to make sure it is flushed to stdout:

```
printf("%s\n", node->data);
```