# Creating a cons cell structure via recursive descent parsing

Tags: c, parsing, recursion, scheme, recursive-descent

I'm currently working on a Scheme Interpreter written in C. I'm trying to create a cons cell structure via recursive descent parsing, except instead of just having the car and cons, I also have a field that holds the token that I receive from the lexical analyzer (which was provided to us). The `struct` for what I'm describing is as such:

```
typdef struct node node;

typedef node* list;

struct node { 
    char* symbol;
    list car;
    list cdr;
};
```

Thus a cons cell would be (with a node represented as `[symbol][car][cdr]`), `[null][car][cdr]`, while a symbol would be `[symbol][null][null]`.

For example, `(a b c)` would be represented as:
[image]

And `(a (b c) d)`, would be represented as:
[image]

This previous post on stack overflow: [Cons Cell data structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115562/cons-cell-data-structure-in-c) is pretty much dealing with the same assignment. In the top answer by Jason for that post, one of his suggestions is to put the tokens into a stack as the input is recursively parsed, and then from that stack input it into the cons cell structure.

This is something that I'm working towards now, as it is easier for me to understand and I already have implemented a stack in C before, but I know that I can just build the structure recursively, I'm just not sure how. The following is pseudo code that I have:

```
list s_expression() {
    list local;
    list temp;

    if (token == "(") {
        token = getToken();
        local = new node;
        local -> car = s_expression()
        temp = local;

        while (token != ")") {
            temp -> rest = new node;
            temp = temp -> rest;
            temp -> first = s_expression()
        }

        temp -> rest = NULL;
        token = getToken();
    } else if (token == symbol) {
        list symbolNode = new node;
        symbolNode -> symbol = token;
        token = getToken()
        return symbolNode;
    } else {
        return local;
    }
}
```

`s_expression` is supposed to return a pointer to a recursively built cons cell structure. I'm just having issues figuring out when to call `getToken()`, as I either call `getToken` in the wrong spot and unintentionally skip over a token, or I call `getToken()` when I'm done getting all of the tokens, thus causing my program to continue searching for a token from user input instead of continuing on with the rest of the program.

When should I be calling `getToken()`?

In addition, what would be better, recursively building the cons cell structure as you go through the user's input, or putting all of the tokens into a stack and then building the cons cell structure using that stack?

If needed, I can post the lexical analyzer that's been provided to us.

Comment: Where is the first token read in before `token == "("`? What if the very next token is `)`?

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry. I can't believe I missed that ( I spend so much time reviewing this question too before I posted it). In a separate function, I get the first token, then I call s_expression(). If the first token is ( and the very next token is ) then those two become a new token () (the empty list), this is handled in the lexical analyzer given to us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking if the very first thing you read is a symbol then there are no other tokens so symbol reading should not get new token. This is also true when you are finished reading a list.

When token is "(" and read either a symbol or expression you will not have a new token after that. Thus before the predicate in the while you need to read new token since you know you are searching for the end of the list. That means before you enter the while loop and after you read `s_expression` in the body.

**Other observations**

The predicate `token == symbol` seems strange. Are you only allowing the same symbol? Are there other data types than lists and symbols to justify not just having `else` here?

The last `else` (alternative) is never hit. Thus when reading a list you never return anything.